# Download zip file from S3 using API Gateway directly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

Is it possible to download Zip file present in S3 using API Gateway alone.

Configurations:

Integration type : AWS Service (S3)

endpoint : GET

**Content-Type: application/zip (or) application/octet-stream**

A corrupted zip file is getting downloaded.

I could able to do a workaround using **S3 presigned url** and don't want to make the bucket public.

Comment: It's impossible to answer this as written. You need to at least define "corrupted": are you getting a zero-length file? If not, what is the size compared to the file you think you're downloading? What is the content, does it look like a zip file or something else?

Comment: @Parsifal the original file size is 5 mb but the GET call from api gateway gives 9mb file, when I tried to unzip throws error like The compressed file is invalid

Comment: OK, so what's inside that file? Is it Base64 encoded?

Comment: FWIW, I recommend that you use an HTTP Proxy integration type rather than an AWS Service integration.

Answer (score 0):

The file can get corrupted when some headers are missing from the upload PUT request. Please make sure the file is not-corrupted by downloading it manually and checking. If it's corrupted from the GET request only please make sure you include all the needed headers in the GET request too.